# Error using FiddlerCore with proxy auto config file (PAC)

Tags: proxy, fiddler, pac

I'm using the stock SampleApp included with FiddlerCore. Http traffic works fine. For Https traffic, I'm getting the following message from FiddlerCore:

[Fiddler] Failed to read HTTPS request from (iexplore:6200) new client socket, port 1294.

makecert.exe is in the application folder.

Does FiddlerCore work with proxy auto config files (PAC)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should have read more carefully.

https://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp

I wasn't trusting the generated cert.

Comment: Yes, FiddlerCore works fine with PAC files. Also note that you'll see periodic "Failure to read ..." warnings from FiddlerCore even when nothing is wrong-- sometimes the browser opens sockets but doesn't use them.